# Is there a command line tool or a library which can convert between indesign templates and CSS/Html?

Tags: css, html, converters, adobe-indesign

I'm looking to (programmatically) convert a repository of Adobe Indesign template files (.indd) to something more easily manipulated by humans (ie, CSS/HTML files).

I'm more interested in an accurate conversion, than a fully readable one - the resulting files will be read by humans, and eventually made more readable.

Is there a tool or library I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the only viable solution to convert from InDesign to html5 seems to be the "In5" plugin developed by Ajar Productions. I doubt it'll allow for bulk conversion but it seems to make a good job as regards accuracy.

Product and a detailed list of its features here: http://www.ajarproductions.com/pages/products/in5/